# Netbeans - Include CSS for all files

Tags: html, css, netbeans

I built my own template system with php.
A short example just to explain my problem:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include('body.html'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, when I open with Netbeans the body.html file

```
<div class="content">
    Hello
</div>
```

Netbeans say: Class content not found

Is it possible to assign the css file to the html file, so that Netbeans find the class?

Comment: It will work in the browser. Why do you need this in your code editor?

Comment: So that I can see if a class is really not defined. And the warnings nervs.

Comment: can you show us content of `body.html` ?

Comment: you see it in the example, it is just the problem, that netbeans don't know that this is a template system and the html will be include by the script...

Comment: Are you sure your file reference in the `link` tag is correct? Right now, it's saying move up one directory before jumping into the css folder. If there is no directory to move up to, you'll get an error.

Comment: The second part is an own file, it is a template system wich include the files. On the server it works, but netbeans don't know that this is a template system. I thought it is possible to say netbeans: Hey it is a template system, use this css file for validate

Answer (score 3):

best to shoot it for the help of PHP but in the opposite way:

pgup.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/main.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
```

index.php

```
    <?php include('pgup.php'); ?>

<div id="content" class="content">
    Hello
</div>
        <?php include('pgdown.php'); ?>
```

pgdown.php

```
    </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
/*(for id)*/
#content{

}

/*(or for class)*/
.content{

}
```

Comment: I think this is the widely adopted approach, but there's one drawback: if the footer is a little more complicated, we have to overcome the paranoia of another warning 'Stray end tag "xxx"', which I have failed to.

Answer (score 0):

*Class content not found :*

```
     **This means, the class named "content" is not defined or not found in HTML/CSS file(s).**
```

**So, either create a new CSS file and make a reference from the html page or use  tag to define the CSS definition in the body.html itself.**

[image: way to CSS]

Comment: But the style is definied in the first file, and I just search a way that, netbeans notice, that it is a template system and that the the css defined in the main file.

Comment: @Laire How did you create the Project Initially? It must be created with File->New Project. And Under _categroies_ ,choose **PHP**